# System.Configuration: Question on the Configuration.Save method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-config

What is the difference between `configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true)` and `configuration.Save()`?

**Background:** I have a programme, where I manipulate a `web.config`, which I use for configuring **WCF Services**. I load it into a `Configuration` object, change some attributes and save it back. When I use `configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true)` I get an `Exception` like this:

*"It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level..."*

When I use `configuration.Save()`, then it works! The reason for the exception may be the section `<serviceActivations>` in my web.config (the exception points to this section)

Answer (score 1):

The default parameters to Save are:

```
Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, false);
```

So the only difference would be that you force saving the configuration, even if it was unchanged. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134089.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Why woyld you write `configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true`) when:

- ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified means:
  [Causes only modified properties to
  be written to the configuration file,
  even when the value is the same as
  the inherited value.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsavemode.aspx)
- true means: [true to save even if the
  configuration was not modified;
  otherwise, false.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134089.aspx)

Isn't the first option the opposite of the second?

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified` only saves the parts of the configuration that are different to the application/system configuration to a user local or roaming configuration (i.e. using [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265.aspx) with `ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming` or `ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal`).

Since ASP.NET doesn't have user levels (and user isolated storage) this doesn't make sense.

From the documentation is not clear if any of the [`Configuration.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.save.aspx) overloads will really work in the case of ASP.NET which uses a completely different configuration setting inheritance model to non-ASP.NET .NET applications. In practice using one of the [`WebConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) to load the configuration manager is likely to be a necessary pre-condition to saving the file.

Another approach might be to explicitly load a explicitly designated file with [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx).